# Use a subdomain instead of https://storage.googleapis.com

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-storage

I am newbie at cloud servers and I've opened a google cloud server but when I try to share the file with others I get the following URL: https://storage.googleapis.com

So my questions is how to use a sub domain instead of the URL shown above EX: cloud.mydomain.com

Thank You!

Answer (score 1):

You've got three major options.

Option 1: Create a bucket named "cloud.mydomain.com", then create a CNAME DNS record redirecting traffic to that domain to GCS. Pros: simpler setup. Documentation: [Hosting a Static Webservice](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/hosting-static-website)

Option 2: Set up a Google Cloud Load Balancer that services that domain, and configure it to serve content from a GCS bucket that you own. Pros: more customizable, can serve other content from same domain. Cons: Alpha. Documentation: [HTTP(S) Load Balancing with Google Cloud Storage](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/load-balancing/http/using-http-lb-with-cloud-storage).

Option 3: Just serve from storage.googleapis.com. It's easy and works fine for many use cases. You can also use mybucketname.storage.googleapis.com.